# 少し日本語を話します and 少し日本語を話せます - What's the difference?

Tags: usage, conjugations, potential-form

What changes, in these phrases? The change is the し for the せ. A friend told me that the second one was better for saying *I speak little japanese*.

> 私は少し日本語を話**し**ます。
>
> 私は少し日本語を話**せ**ます。

Comment: `A friend told me that the second one was better for saying I speak little japanese` >> "I speak little Japanese" (w/o "a") would be 私は日本語がほとんど話せません, whereas 私は少し日本語を話せます would be "I can speak **a** little Japanese"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 私は少し日本語を話します。

I will speak a little Japanese. (starting now)

> 私は少し日本語を話せます。

I can speak a little Japanese. (the ability to speak)

On a side note, a quick grammar fix (leaving word order as is)

私は少し日本語**が**話せます。

Comment: Although you wrote that it's a grammar fix, native speakers frequently use both が and を.   Some discussion: http://www.ritsumei.ac.jp/acd/cg/lt/rb/599/599pdf/higasiya.pdf

Comment: In the [Google Japanese Web N-gram](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2009T08) corpus, I find 2889 results for 日本語**が**話せます, and 1690 results for 日本語**を**話せます.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks for that. I'll have a read.

Comment: Why is が better?

Answer (score 4):

Just copied & pasted from [my half-year-old answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19733/7810) (though the question itself isn't a duplicate):

---

> Though I translated 日本語を話す into "speak Japanese", the verb doesn't have "be able to speak" sense, so every time you have to explicitly use potential form when you question about ability.
>
> > 日本語が話せますか？
> > *Do you speak Japanese?*
>
> compared to:
>
> > 日本語を話しますか？
> > *Are you going to speak Japanese?*

---

Answer (score 1):

The second one is the **potential** form of the verb.  I **can** speak a little Japanese.  Although when using the potential, が is usually preferred over を.

> 日本語**が**話せます

Here are some references on the potential form.

---

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Potential)
- [Tae Kim's Guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/potential)
- [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/78)