Adjective placement?
Where do you typically place adjectives in Japanese?
I was taught that they typically go before the modified noun, but I see Google translate sometimes but them before the verb.
For example, it translates "I understand a little Japanese" as "日本語を少しわかります" whereas I would have expected it to place 少し at the beginning like "少し日本語をわかります".
Does this order matter? Is one more correct than the other?

少し is not an adjective, which may clear up some of the issues that you're having.

In English terms: "a little bit" isn't a kind of "Japanese"; it's a description of the speaker's "understanding".

少し works adverbially in the sentence, and the order does not matter much Adverb position before object / before verb . That aside, it should be 日本語がわかります

In Japanese, an adjective always comes (somewhere) before the noun it modifies, and an adverb always comes (somewhere) before the verb it modifies. Japanese is a completely head-final language.
In the sentence 日本語を少しわかります, 少し is an adverb, and it modifies the verb right after it, わかります. The Japanese sentence in question is structurally closer to "I understand Japanese a little" rather than "I understand a little Japanese".
However, 少し日本語をわかります is also perfectly correct, and the meaning of the sentence remains exactly the same. 少し is always an adverb, and thus it modifies the next verb, わかります, even though there is another noun (日本語) in between.

Wouldn't 腰が痛い be an example where the adjective comes after the noun?

@GuiImamura That 痛い is not modifying anything because it's the main predicate (述語) of the sentence. I said "an adjective always comes (somewhere) before the noun it modifies".

少しは日本語の前に置ければ、名詞になりますので、少しと日本語の間にはのを入れるべきだと思います。

「『少し日本語がわかります。』は誤りで、『少しの日本語がわかります。』とすべきだ」、というご意見でしょうか？

両方も正しいと思いますが、「少し」は「日本語」の前に置いたら、なんか不自然な感じがしますって、それは私個人的な意見です。

Not sure why I got voted down, but if you do a Google search for "少しの", there are numerous hits including reputable sites like Weblio. This sort of construction is pretty commonplace.

I think you got downvoted simply because your answer in Japanese is difficult to interpret. But if you're suggesting to use 少しの日本語, then that's not correct, either. 少しの日本語 can refer to a small fragment of Japanese text, but it's unnatural to use it when you say "I can speak a little Japanese". That's why Google Translate changed the sentence structure a bit and used an adverb to express this idea.

How about you search for "少しの日本語を話せる"? 8380 hits, including stuff written by native Japanese-speakers. This sort of construction is perfectly OK. I don't care much for Google Translate. If you have to point to a machine translation service to prove your point... Well, I'm afraid that's not very convincing.

Google hit counts are very unstable and unreliable. I can only see 20 examples with the same query, which doesn't prove that it's natural. Instead, you need to use a corpus like BCCWJ to check this. In BCCWJ, there are no instances of 少しのX語 and many instances of X語が少し and X語を少し. I'm not saying 少しの日本語 is ungrammatical or incomprehensible. I'm saying nearly all native speakers prefer X語を少し話す over 少しのX語を話す.

Thanks for informing me of BCCWJ. I will take some time to look into it. I do agree that 「日本語を少し話せる」is vastly preferrable over 「少しの日本語を話せる」. That said, I also find the latter perfectly acceptable, or it wouldn't have ended up in Weblio. Anyway, let's end this argument, shall we?

@Evelyn, I agree with ＠naruto that 少しの日本語 ... it's unnatural to use it when you say "I can speak a little Japanese". 「XX語が少し話せる」「少しXX語が話せる」 sound natural to my native ears, but I wouldn't say 「少しのXX語が話せる」. 実際、「スミス先生は少しの日本語が話せます」とか「スミス先生は少しの日本語がわかります」とは言わないですねぇ。。まあ意味は分かりますけど。Just so you know, @naruto and I are both native Japanese speakers, so I don't think we need to point to a machine translation service or google hit counts to prove our point.

I'm not the downvoter, but I disagree that 「『少し』は『日本語』の前に置け(れ)ば名詞になります...」. 「少し」は「日本語」の後ろに置いても前に置いても副詞です。参考まで: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25721/9831
